# LibreOffice Draw project file size fluctuates hugely

Tags: libreoffice

I am designing books into Draw and I noticed something very strange. Same project today is 1.8GB and a save later (same project) takes 200MB. Then I save again (no or little changes) and takes 2GB. Save another time and takes 1.3GB, and yet another time and takes 700MB. I have no idea why this can fluctuate so much since it is basically the same project....

Any clue? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

In the OpenOffice forum (OpenOffice is broadly similar to LibreOffice) https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=84228 there is a similar thread about file sizes which gives good information on possible reasons for what you are experiencing.

Essentially, it suggests that the system may be allocating extra space for the file based on the bit rate on your drive and/or maybe that you should get your drive checked for bad sectors as the system may be trying to save the data to a suspect area of your drive.

So, personally, I doubt it is a bug but just that your system is doing its job properly in protecting your data by writing it to disk areas which have good integrity.

But, just to be on the safe side, do remember that you are only as good as your last backup (and you can't have too many of them!) so regularly save your work perhaps to one of the many online/offsite data sources rather than commit valuable work to a potentially dodgy HD.

Comment: Hm I doubt it could be my SSD since I remember seeing this behavior on other systems that I have (laptops).